# Can't set Launch images for universal application

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen, launch-screen

I tried to follow several tutorials, but nothing happened. First of all, I had created new LaunchImage asset and filled it with images:

[image]

Then I've chosen this asset in Launch Image Source:

[image]

I guess I did enough to make it work, but when I launch my app I see nothing except wight launch screen, can you help me to make it work?

When I enter this asset name in UIImageView in LaunchScreen StoryBoard, this asset is invisible and I only have the huge sign of question:

[image]

Can you help me?

I added the target of my asset but nothing happened:

[image]

Comment: In your project open LaunchScreen.storyboard and add the image in that view controller.

Comment: @Uma Is it possible to add image on controller or I should firstly add UIImageView on that controller and then add my image asset on UIImageView?

Comment: you need to add image view and then add the image.

Comment: @Uma You are right, I tried to do it. But when I try to enter asset name in image property of UIImageView, Xcode doesn't see any asset, after I entered it nothing happened

Comment: reset simulator and try once.

Comment: @Uma I tested it on device. I'd deleted the app and installed it again, now to works, thank you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that you have not added the `Images.xcassets` to its target. Add the target membership of your xcassets file.

[image]

Comment: I edited question and added the picture, I have the mark in that field.

Comment: I tested it on device. I'd deleted the app and installed it again, now to works, thank you!)